# How to remove 1 second hold delay while drag/drop list view item on Windows Phone 10?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10-mobile

For Windows 10, on desktop drag/drop ListViewItem does not require holding 1 second, but on the phone it does. Any idea how to remove this 1 second holding requirement?

Comment: I had the same behavior on desktop actually and not on mobile. Recently the same behavior appeared on mobile too. I'm still targeting 10586. Dragging with a mouse doesn't require to hold.

Answer (score 0):

> For Windows 10, on desktop drag/drop ListViewItem does not require holding 1 second, but on the phone it does.

For on the phone, we using a touch gesture for dragging instead of mouse click on the desktop. Press and hold will trigger the dragging on the phone is as design. Details please reference [Open a context menu on an item you can drag with touch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/drag-and-drop#open-a-context-menu-on-an-item-you-can-drag-with-touch).

> Any idea how to remove this 1 second holding requirement?

We cannot remove the holding requirements by using the drag and drop APIs.But for touch actions we can use [`Manipulation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227934) relative events to implement your requirements. For example,for dragging one element from one place to another we can use [UIElement.ManipulationDelta](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationdelta) event to transfom the element by class like [CompositeTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.compositetransform.aspx). The scenario 5 of [Basic Input official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicInput) has similar features which use `Manipulation` to implement you can reference.

You can use the following simple code to test the series of `Manipulation` events can triggered with out holding.

XAML code

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txttestdrag" CanDrag="True" Text="drag test" DragStarting="txttestdrag_DragStarting" ManipulationMode="All"  ManipulationStarted="txttestdrag_ManipulationStarted"></TextBlock>
```

Code behind

```
 private void txttestdrag_DragStarting(UIElement sender, DragStartingEventArgs args)
 {

 } 
 private void txttestdrag_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

Comment: Hi Sunteen, thank you again for answering my question. Let me go run some practice on this example and will come back to mark it as answer as soon as i confirm.

Comment: As expected using the manipulation framework is much more difficult than simply handling a couple of drag and drop events...